# Linear independence/dependence of the set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

**My problem**: Show the linear dependence on chosen set of scalars. Find the subset $M\subset \mathbb C^2$ which is linear independent if we consider $\mathbb C^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ and is linear dependent if we consider $\mathbb C^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$.

Well, that given set is *dependent* if there is a nontrivial linear combination which is zero, otherwise *independent*.

Unfortunately I haven't been succesful in that searching. Any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: Don´t You mean the given set is dependent if there is a nontrivial linear combination which is zero and otherwise independent?

Comment: Think of $(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)$...

Comment: Yes, I meant that, I will edit it.

Comment: the trick is to use the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspaces

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I haven't realised that.

Comment: You´re welcome!